# PHP ob_start() for file caching

Tags: php, caching, ob-start

when this sample web page loads, it checks cached file from /cache folder. If there is no cached file, it calls ob_start() and creates a .html cache file. Problem is this caching process is working everytime even I have not called ob_start(). Please advise me. Thank you.

```
// class file
function check_cache($dynamic_url) {
  $cache_file = $this->cache_folder.md5($dynamic_url).$this->cache_ext;
  if ((file_exists($cache_file)) && (time() - $this->cache_time < filemtime($cache_file))) {
   // ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
      readfile($cache_file);
      ob_end_flush();                
      exit();
   }
   else {
      //ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
  }
}

function create_cache($dynamic_url) {
  $cache_file = $this->cache_folder.md5($dynamic_url).$this->cache_ext;
  $fp = fopen($cache_file, 'w');
  fwrite($fp, ob_get_contents());
  fclose($fp);
  ob_end_flush();
}
```

and I call this class from

```
$cache->check_cache(get_full_url());
<h1>Today is <?php echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s'); ?></h1>             
$cache->create_cache(get_full_url());
```

Comment: What is the meaning of "but ob_end_flush() seems working"? If you call the ob_end_flush() but have not called ob_start(), the ob_end_flush() will do nothing.

Comment: That's what I was expected... as you can see I have not called ob_start() but it is keep caching a page...

Answer (score 0):

I think that your cache is still created because of your create_cache calling fopen no matter what the output buffer is started or not. Therefore, should check your output buffer status before do fopen, as follows:

```
 function create_cache($dynamic_url) {
    if (ob_get_level() > 0) {
         $cache_file = $this->cache_folder.md5($dynamic_url).$this->cache_ext;
         $fp = fopen($cache_file, 'w');
         fwrite($fp, ob_get_contents());
         fclose($fp);
         ob_end_flush();
    }
}
```

You can use ob_get_level or ob_get_status: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-status.php